# How to get 7 day weather forecast using Yahoo API in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, yahoo-weather-api

I have made a sample Android app for the weather forecast for the 7 day, I have made is using following link:

[weather forecast](http://androidcodebits.wordpress.com/2013/07/20/integration-of-yahoo-weather-api-in-android/)

I know that there are two parameters in Yahoo weather api "w" and "u" but I don't know how to get 7 day weather forecast by changing that parameters. Please tell me what changes I should make to get 7 day weather forecast in place of 5 day. My code is as below:

**myxml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weatherLink"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#cecece"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Weather Link"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/weather_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#cecece"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Weather"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/weather_border"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/weather_title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#CCCCCC" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer_border"
        android:layout_below="@+id/weather_border" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dateText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tempText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/dateText"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/conditionText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tempText"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/humidityText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/conditionText"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/windText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/humidityText"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/border2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/windText"
                android:background="#ff6600" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/forecast_title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/border2"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="Forecast"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/forecastBorder"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/forecast_title"
                android:background="#CCCCCC" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/forecastBorder"
                android:background="#cecece"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/day1"
                android:background="#cecece"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/day2"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/day3"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/day4"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/day5"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/day7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/day6"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:padding="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/footer_border"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:background="#CCCCCC" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#E4E4E4" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/reportBtn"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/footer"
        android:background="#ffff00"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/backBtn"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/footer"
        android:background="#aaaaaa"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**main.java**

```
package com.example.weekreport;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String temperature, date, condition, humidity, wind, link;
    Bitmap icon = null;
    TextView title, tempText, dateText, conditionText, windText, humidityText,
            weatherLink, day1, day2, day3, day4, day5, day6, day7;
    ImageView image;
    ArrayList<String> weather = new ArrayList<String>();
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weather_title);
        dateText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateText);
        tempText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempText);
        conditionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.conditionText);
        humidityText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humidityText);
        windText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.windText);
        day1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day1);
        day2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day2);
        day3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day3);
        day4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day4);
        day2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day5);
        day3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day6);
        day4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.day7);
        weatherLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weatherLink);
        /*
         * Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
         * “Fonts/Roboto-Condensed.ttf”);
         */
        title.setText("My Weather Report");
        /*
         * tempText.setTypeface(tf); conditionText.setTypeface(tf);
         * dateText.setTypeface(tf); humidityText.setTypeface(tf);
         * windText.setTypeface(tf); title.setTypeface(tf);
         * day1.setTypeface(tf); day2.setTypeface(tf); day3.setTypeface(tf);
         * day4.setTypeface(tf);
         */
        ImageButton backBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.backBtn);
        ImageButton report = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reportBtn);

        new retrieve_weatherTask().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    protected class retrieve_weatherTask extends
            AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Please wait...");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String qResult = "";
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                    "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2295425&u=c&#8221");

            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet,
                        localContext);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                if (entity != null) {
                    InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                    BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(in);
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String stringReadLine = null;
                    while ((stringReadLine = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(stringReadLine + "\n");
                    }
                    qResult = stringBuilder.toString();
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            Document dest = null;
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder parser;
            try {
                parser = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                dest = parser
                        .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(qResult.getBytes()));
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e1.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            Node temperatureNode = dest.getElementsByTagName(
                    "yweather:condition").item(0);
            temperature = temperatureNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("temp")
                    .getNodeValue().toString();
            Node tempUnitNode = dest.getElementsByTagName("yweather:units")
                    .item(0);
            temperature = temperature
                    + "°"
                    + tempUnitNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("temperature")
                            .getNodeValue().toString();

            Node dateNode = dest.getElementsByTagName("yweather:forecast")
                    .item(0);
            date = dateNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("date").getNodeValue()
                    .toString();

            Node conditionNode = dest
                    .getElementsByTagName("yweather:condition").item(0);
            condition = conditionNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("text")
                    .getNodeValue().toString();

            Node humidityNode = dest
                    .getElementsByTagName("yweather:atmosphere").item(0);
            humidity = humidityNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("humidity")
                    .getNodeValue().toString();
            humidity = humidity + "%";

            Node windNode = dest.getElementsByTagName("yweather:wind").item(0);
            wind = windNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("speed")
                    .getNodeValue().toString();
            Node windUnitNode = dest.getElementsByTagName("yweather:units")
                    .item(0);
            wind = wind
                    + " "
                    + windUnitNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("speed")
                            .getNodeValue().toString();

            String desc = dest.getElementsByTagName("item").item(0)
                    .getChildNodes().item(13).getTextContent().toString();
            StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(desc, "<=>");
            System.out.println("Tokens: " + str.nextToken("=>"));
            String src = str.nextToken();
            System.out.println("src: " + src);
            String url1 = src.substring(1, src.length() - 2);
            Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("(.+?)<br />");
            Matcher matcher = TAG_REGEX.matcher(desc);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                weather.add(matcher.group(1));
            }

            Pattern links = Pattern.compile("(.+?)<BR/>");
            matcher = links.matcher(desc);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("Match Links: " + (matcher.group(1)));
                link = matcher.group(1);
            }

            /*
             * String test = (Html.fromHtml(desc)).toString();
             * System.out.println(“test: “+ test); StringTokenizer tkn = new
             * StringTokenizer(test); for(int i=0; i < tkn.countTokens(); i++){
             * System.out.println(“Remaining: “+tkn.nextToken()); }
             */

            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                // in = OpenHttpConnection(url1);
                int response = -1;
                URL url = new URL(url1);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
                    throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
                HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConn.connect();

                response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    System.out.println("*********************");
                    in = httpConn.getInputStream();
                }
                icon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return qResult;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            System.out.println("POST EXECUTE");

            if (dialog.isShowing() && dialog != null)
                dialog.dismiss();
            tempText.setText("Temperature:" + temperature);
            conditionText.setText("Condition: " + condition);
            dateText.setText("Date: " + date);
            humidityText.setText("Humidity: " + humidity);
            windText.setText("Wind: " + wind);
            image.setImageBitmap(icon);
            day1.setText(weather.get(3));
            day2.setText(weather.get(4));
            day3.setText(weather.get(5));
            day4.setText(weather.get(6));
            day5.setText(weather.get(1));
            day6.setText(weather.get(2));

            weatherLink.setText(Html.fromHtml(link));

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What makes you think you can get a 7 day forecast this way?  Did you read http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/ ?

Comment: I can make it or not?

Comment: There's no mention of a 7 day forecast service anywhere on the API doc page.  Weather.com, the service that powers Yahoo weather offers a *paying* service with a 10 day forecast window - see here http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/?ref=twc

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [API specification](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/) for Yahoo weather, it doesn't mention anything about a 7 day forecast, and from the example responses it appears to only be the imminent forecast.

Your best option is to try an alternative, such as [WorldWeatherOnline](http://developer.worldweatheronline.com/io-docs), they have a free API which does allow you to specify a number of days.

You need to register for a free API key, but once you've done that you could request using:

`http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=London&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=`

You'd get a response such as

```
{
    "data": {
        "current_condition": [{
            "cloudcover": "75",
            "humidity": "87",
            "observation_time": "01:48 PM",
            "precipMM": "0.0",
            "pressure": "998",
            "temp_C": "4",
            "temp_F": "39",
            "visibility": "8",
            "weatherCode": "116",
            "weatherDesc": [{
                "value": "Partly Cloudy"
            }],
            "weatherIconUrl": [{
                "value": "http:\/\/cdn.worldweatheronline.net\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png"
            }],
            "winddir16Point": "WSW",
            "winddirDegree": "250",
            "windspeedKmph": "17",
            "windspeedMiles": "11"
        }],
        "request": [{
            "query": "London, United Kingdom",
            "type": "City"
        }],
        "weather": [{
            "date": "2013-12-26",
            "precipMM": "0.1",
            "tempMaxC": "6",
            "tempMaxF": "43",
            "tempMinC": "3",
            "tempMinF": "37",
            "weatherCode": "113",
            "weatherDesc": [{
                "value": "Sunny"
            }],
            "weatherIconUrl": [{
                "value": "http:\/\/cdn.worldweatheronline.net\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
            }],
            "winddir16Point": "WSW",
            "winddirDegree": "248",
            "winddirection": "WSW",
            "windspeedKmph": "20",
            "windspeedMiles": "13"
        }, {
            "date": "2013-12-27",
            "precipMM": "3.4",
            "tempMaxC": "10",
            "tempMaxF": "51",
            "tempMinC": "4",
            "tempMinF": "40",
            "weatherCode": "113",
            "weatherDesc": [{
                "value": "Sunny"
            }],
            "weatherIconUrl": [{
                "value": "http:\/\/cdn.worldweatheronline.net\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
            }],
            "winddir16Point": "SW",
            "winddirDegree": "214",
            "winddirection": "SW",
            "windspeedKmph": "43",
            "windspeedMiles": "27"
        }, {
            "date": "2013-12-28",
            "precipMM": "0.4",
            "tempMaxC": "8",
            "tempMaxF": "46",
            "tempMinC": "1",
            "tempMinF": "34",
            "weatherCode": "116",
            "weatherDesc": [{
                "value": "Partly Cloudy"
            }],
            "weatherIconUrl": [{
                "value": "http:\/\/cdn.worldweatheronline.net\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png"
            }],
            "winddir16Point": "SW",
            "winddirDegree": "216",
            "winddirection": "SW",
            "windspeedKmph": "16",
            "windspeedMiles": "10"
        }, {
            "date": "2013-12-29",
            "precipMM": "0.0",
            "tempMaxC": "6",
            "tempMaxF": "42",
            "tempMinC": "3",
            "tempMinF": "37",
            "weatherCode": "113",
            "weatherDesc": [{
                "value": "Sunny"
            }],
            "weatherIconUrl": [{
                "value": "http:\/\/cdn.worldweatheronline.net\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
            }],
            "winddir16Point": "WSW",
            "winddirDegree": "259",
            "winddirection": "WSW",
            "windspeedKmph": "22",
            "windspeedMiles": "14"
        }, {
            "date": "2013-12-30",
            "precipMM": "4.3",
            "tempMaxC": "9",
            "tempMaxF": "49",
            "tempMinC": "5",
            "tempMinF": "42",
            "weatherCode": "113",
            "weatherDesc": [{
                "value": "Sunny"
            }],
            "weatherIconUrl": [{
                "value": "http:\/\/cdn.worldweatheronline.net\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
            }],
            "winddir16Point": "SW",
            "winddirDegree": "227",
            "winddirection": "SW",
            "windspeedKmph": "36",
            "windspeedMiles": "23"
        }]
    }
}
```

That should do what you want :)

Comment: Nice service, do read their [TOS](http://developer.worldweatheronline.com/free_api_terms_of_use) though - just like all other free or sampler or dev API keys they have pretty strict usage limitations...

Comment: Ah, and, from http://developer.worldweatheronline.com/ : free api == Current conditions plus 5 day weather, 24 hourly

Comment: Good call on the TOS :). I didn't spot the 5 day restriction on the free API, but a quick Google for "free weather forecast 7 days" returns other results such as http://www.myweather2.com/developer/apis.aspx. If the OP put his location on profile we could suggest something more localised (if that is a requirement of course)

Comment: Any buddy tell me how can i get 10 day forecast for "FREE"..

Comment: @Jimmy-Thank you but can you give me any request url or response in json or xml??

Comment: @Jimmy-http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=London&format=json&num_of_days=5&key= in that key parameter is what?i give my key but i am not getting response..

Comment: @Jimmy-i have used it but get response for just today....i want it for 7 days......!

Comment: @jigarjims Did you set the `num_of_days` query parameter like I did above? If so, you should see a number of days, like my example which displays December 26th thru 30th.

Comment: @Jimmy--Please review my request as below:http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=Mumbai&format=json&num_of_days=7&key="my key"............but i am getting only today's weather....!!!

Comment: @jimmy-i got upto 5 days...but i want 7 days........! when i enter 7 days it just give me today;s weahter...!!!